# Cron job in google cloud is showing status failed

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, cron

I am currently working in Google clouds and i have deployed my python application in Google app engine. now i want to schedule tasks in it. i have read it. Google clouds is doing this through cron jobs. i have written a very basic cron and trying to run it.  but every time it failing. can anyone please tell me what is going wrong.
here is my **app.yaml**

```
handlers:
- url: /laptop/
  script: file.py
  login: admin
```

and my **cron.yaml** file is

```
cron:
- description: daily summary job
  url: /laptop
  target: beta
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

my file which i want to run is in **myproject/laptop/file.py**

and my **file.py** is only printing my name (just for testing purpose)

```
print "Amad";
print "testing"
```

can anybody tell me, how can i run this file on Google app engine.

when i run this cron on task queues it gives me error like this.
[image]

please refer me some tutorial where i can successfully run it. i have waste a lot of my time on it.
Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: logs are not showing on google cloud for it :( any other way to view logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can view all your apps logs including any error messages by clicking the "hamburger" button in the top left and selecting "Logging".

There you should see the cause of the error in your cron handler.

Possible problem: perhaps your handler should not end with /

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to set up your file.py to be similar to a regular main.py (can't tell if you've done so but based on your contents of file.py it doesn't seem so) Copy and paste the sample tutorial code from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart, and put your print statements in the get method

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        print "Amad";
        print "testing"


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

This should solve your problem if the other files are ok, like app.yaml (refer to link for sample code on this)